# Deployment of a CMS written in Classic ASP via Git

Tags: git, iis, deployment, asp-classic

We have a CMS written in Classic ASP. Instances are hosted on Windows servers, via IIS.

For source control, we have recently started using Git towards an internal server. We are currently deploying new versions by manually copying files onto the server, for example via FTP.

Obviously, manually copying the files over isn't the ideal way to deploy new code, so we're looking into automatically deploying updates to different targets (test, staging and production servers).

Amongst the alternatives we have considers, these are the three front runners:

1. Using a continuous integration server to pull the latest code from Git and automatically copy the necessary files into the server. (We already use TeamCity for C# ASP.NET projects.)
2. Making use of Git hooks and custom scripts to automatically copy files onto the server, based on Git tags, a "label" in the commit message, or something along those lines.
3. Cloning the Git repository onto the server itself, and then either manually or automatically doing a fetch via Git whenever we want to deploy a new version.

Since there are no automated tests or other "build procedures" for this particular CMS, we feel like alternative 1, although it's probably "the most proper solution", might be a bit overkill. As far as I know, we only need to copy a set of files from the Git server to the application server.

Which one of these approaches would be the best, and what would be some pros and cons to consider with each solutions? Does anyone know of a better/cleaner way to deploy a Classic ASP site via Git?

I would very much appreciate any input and suggestions on this.

Comment: Git runs on windows - the win version comes with a shell which allows you to use unix style commands